# Still shows example app after setting Everyplay Client ID and secret

Tags: everyplay

I registered a developer account and added a game. Then I added the client id and secret to the app with

```
[Everyplay setClientId:xxx clientSecret:xxx redirectURI:xxx];
```

and tried to upload a video. But it showed the example app instead of the name and icon of my game. Did I miss some steps? Or is this normal behaviour for development build? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried logging out trough the settings menu? If you have previously shared (or visited the sharing screen) or otherwise logged in using the example app credentials a login token has been created and stored matching those details. If this is the case, simple logout should solve the problem.

Hope this helps.